# XMPP multi device sync with xmpp chat message

Tags: ios

XMPP multi device sync : I am trying to develop a messaging application using XMPP. I am trying to implement chat sync on multiple devices per user. But I am able to get the messages only on the logged devices or the first offline device which logs in. Different devices use different resource so that full jabber id is different.

Comment: Please check XMPP message carbon -  https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) in iOS, you can add XMPPMessageCarbons extension

```
var xmppMessageCarbon = XMPPMessageCarbons()
xmppMessageCarbon?.autoEnableMessageCarbons = true
xmppMessageCarbon?.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: xmppQueue)
xmppMessageCarbon?.activate(xmppStream)
```

and  implement its delegates

```
func xmppMessageCarbons(_ xmppMessageCarbons: XMPPMessageCarbons!, willReceive message: XMPPMessage!, outgoing isOutgoing: Bool) {

}

func xmppMessageCarbons(_ xmppMessageCarbons: XMPPMessageCarbons!, didReceive message: XMPPMessage!, outgoing isOutgoing: Bool) {

}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer I used this method and I am getting carbon message in didReceive method but don't know this message not storing in local storage can you please tell me how to store that message on local storage. @oldrinmendez